# Unknown error while loading html embedded pdf in protractor test

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, selenium-webdriver, protractor

My test case is clicking a link which opens pdf in the same browser session. It works fine on chrome but IE and firefox gives unknown error. I am using Protractor 2.4.0 w/ jasmine2.

Here is the log from my local selenium server:

```html
16:08:50.090 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Finding elements with css selector == embed[type='application/pdf']returned an unexpected error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.24 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'nds3370469', ip: '139.172.114.141', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=true, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:24244/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 509639c4-99d3-4369-bf7c-98dfa8dfdce6
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=embed[type='application/pdf']}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:378)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:486)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElements(By.java:441)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:341)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.findElements(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElements(EventFiringWebDriver.java:176)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElements.call(FindElements.java:50)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElements.call(FindElements.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16:08:50.117 WARN - Exception: Finding elements with css selector == embed[type='application/pdf']returned an unexpected error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.24 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'nds3370469', ip: '139.172.114.141', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=true, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:24244/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 509639c4-99d3-4369-bf7c-98dfa8dfdce6
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=embed[type='application/pdf']}
```

```html
<html>  
<body style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38); height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0"><embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="https://dummy-url/image?paymentID=0000107050FAKE11%20%201403FAKE82042302014" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="16">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see your test case please?

Comment: Could we have the Firefox trace too?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are waiting enough for these elements to load? It could be that the page is taking longer time to load in IE and firefox?

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var link = $('#plugin');
var isClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(link);

browser.wait(isClickable, 5000); //wait for an element to become clickable
link.click();
```

## Edit

Try using id in the selector instead of `'embed[type="application/pdf"]` It could be that IE is little quirky about using `/` in the selector. This is just a guess by the way but worth a try.

Comment: I tried with browser.pause and ran that command in repl. Still got the same error:

> $('embed[type="application/pdf"]').isPresent()
UnknownError: Finding elements with css selector == embed[type="application/pdf"]returned an unexpected error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.05 seconds

Comment: How long was the pause for?

Comment: browser.pause() is the breakpoint. Meaning it allows the UI to completely load before interacting with the element. In short, synchronization is not an issue here.

Comment: Try using id in the selector instead of 'embed[type="application/pdf"] It could be that IE is little quirky about using / in the selector. This is just a guess by the way but worth a try. I updated answer

Comment: Since I couldn't inspect element for that page in IE, I tried printing the entire html dom to log. And from that I found out that on IE it's not exposing any html tags. Meaning, the error is expected when I run the tests in IE.